# asp.net value of C# var in JS

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, button, popup

I have a simple JS pop up `"are you sure..."`  window, along with a dropdownlist and `asp:button`.
What I want when I click the button is to get this message:

`"Are you sure you want to perform <%= ACTION %>?"`

where ACTION is a string coming from dropdownlist.SelectedItem.Text.

The following does not seem to work:

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to perform <%= ACTION %>? );
```

It actually just prints the `<%= ACTION %>` instead of the value.

I have also tried:

```
function testMe() {
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to perform ' + document.getElementById('<%= hfAction.ClientID %>').value + '?');
}

OnClientClick="testMe();"
```

But the above causes postback regardless of clicking `cancel` or `OK`.

Which is the correct usage?

Comment: how you have defined ACTION in your C# code

Comment: yes its a simple string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ACTION">
    <asp:ListItem>Action 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Action 2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ExecuteConfirm() {
        var ddlId = '<%= ACTION.UniqueID %>';
        var action = $("#" + ddlId + " option:selected").text();
        return confirm('Are you sure you want to perform ' + action + ' ?');
    }
</script>

<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return ExecuteConfirm();" />
```

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Comment: I used jquery on my sample code. You can use "var action = document.getElementById(ddlId).value;" instead of the like that contains the "var action = $..."

Comment: Ok i was just missing the import in the header. Works fine now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use server tags inside of server control declarations. Set the OnClientClick script in the code behind when initialising the object.

```
mybutton.OnClientClick 
    = string.format("return confirm('Are you sure you want to perform {0}?');", ACTION);
```

Comment: In what sense? Same issue? Error?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my last answer was complete garbage (didn't think before posting).  What about this (you're almost right)?

```
function testMe() {
    var val = document.getElementById('<%= hfAction.ClientID %>').value;
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to perform ' + val + '?');
}

OnClientClick="return testMe();"
```

You just missed the return on the OnClientClick.

Comment: Almost there. The problem I'm having is that it is not picking up the new value of hfAction.value after I select another item on the DDL. If I do a postback only then it picks up the value. I set it like so: `protected void ddlActions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hfAction.Value = ddlActions.SelectedItem.Text;
    }`

Comment: Can you not just query the DDL instead of hfAction then?  So document.getElementById('ddlActions.ClientID').value?